# XSLT 2.0 - How can you change the path for comparison tests

Tags: xslt, xpath, comparison

Right now, I'm able to grab the immediate children of a certain element "root" and these elements have names that contain dashes. So for example, say these immediate children have names 'A4-1','B3-2', and 'C4-3'.

I would like to be able to do something along the lines of the following psuedo-code:

```
for each immediate child
    print out it's child element figtitle/autonum/@ID
```

Is there a way to do something like this without concatenating the path into a string? Each time I concat the immediate child values to the rest of its path, I get a string, so I can't compare it's attribute value to another value, for example:

```
<xsl:if test="*['yes' = (PATH)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="PATH[@ID = 'yes']"/> 
</xsl:if>
```

Where the paths would be:

root/A4-1/figtitle/autonum/@ID
root/B3-2/figtitle/autonum/@ID
root/C4-3/figtitle/autonum/@ID

Comment: I don't understand the question. Pleas provide input sample and desired output.

Comment: You managed to confuse everybody. `$element = {'A4-1','A4-2','A4-3'}

` is not legal syntax for either XSLT or XPath. Please - edit the question and re-formulate.

Comment: Alejandro & Dimitrie - edited the question... hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Comment: Please, see my answer for explanation and quick solution. I also edited your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thank you for the edit - I'm sorry for the confusing question! I'm tyring to make my complex code into a simple, general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The expression you need is**:

```
/root/*/figtitle/autonum/@ID
```

**this means**:

Select all `ID` attributes of any `autonum` element that is a child of a `figtitle` element that is a grandchild of the top element `root`.

If the element `root` isn't the top element of the document, then if the expression would be evaluated with the parent of `root` as the context node, the expression should be:

```
root/*/figtitle/autonum/@ID
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
someElement/*
```

selects all elements that are children of the element named `someElement` that is a child of the context node (current node) against which the expression is evaluated.

Thus, it is not at all necessary to enumerate explicitly the names of the children of `someElement`.

**Update**: The OP has clarified in a comment that she needs to select only those children of `root`, whose names contain dashes, numbers and letters.

**This XPath expression**:

root/*[contains(name(), '-') 
     and 
      translate(name(), $vAlphaNum, ' ') = '']
       /figtitle/autonum/@ID

selects exactly all such elements.

Here, the variable `$vAlphaNum` must be defined to contain all lower and upper case letters and the digits 0-9.

In XSLT 2.0 one can use the `matches()` function with a suitable regular expression.

Comment: @Dimitrie. I'm not looking to select all children of root, I'm trying to select all that contain dashes, letters, and numbers. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Katie, Sure, there is. Could you, please, update your question?